# Filenet P8 how to attach Javadoc for jace.jar

Tags: javadoc, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I'm new to Filenet and I was asked to develop an event action handler in Java.
I'm trying to define a Javadoc for the `jace.jar` library, but with no success.
Does anybody know what's the URL for this Javadoc? (I need it for `com.filenet.api` package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit late for an answer but you could link your Jace.jar Javadoc location to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc

This link points to version 5.2.0, you would need to change it according to your installed version.

Alternatively, you could download the appropriate javadoc from ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cm/filenet/docs/p8doc/52x/ and link it to Jace.jar

Hope this helps

Comment: The first link does not work currently: "The topic was not found. The link might not be correct, or the topic does not exist. Check that the URL is correct and try again."

Comment: The link would not work through a normal browser because it is missing the /index.html at the end. It works perfectly for me when used as a Javadoc location path though.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked for me as a Javadoc location path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a public URL that provides pure Javadoc for CE API. Online [FileNet P8 Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/index.html&overview-summary.html) adds extra framing that probably makes it impossible to use Javadoc from within IDE.

You can grab Javadoc JAR from the deployed P8 Information Center. This is `p8docs.war/WEB-INF/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc_5.1.0.jar`.

Comment: Thanks, but we don't have the information center installed, and I can't install it now. Any other ideas of how I can get this jar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project using P8 CE 5.2.1 and needed to add Javadocs under eclipse to `jace.jar`.

The Javadoc URL simply doesn't work and in eclipse Error Log you can read:

> eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500 java.version=1.8.0_92
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> org.eclipse.jdt.core Error Tue Jan 17 15:58:28 CET 2017 Unknown
>   javadoc format for UserContext
>   {key=Lcom/filenet/api/util/UserContext;} [in UserContext.class [in
>   com.filenet.api.util [in D:\Program
>   Files\apache-maven-3.3.1.m2\repository\com\ibm\ecm\filenet\jace\5.2.1\jace-5.2.1.jar]]]

So I followed @user3282942 suggestion adding a few missing and a little more precise steps:

1. go to ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cm/filenet/docs/p8doc/52x/
2. don't download latest (as far as I'm writing) `p8docs521_refresh_03_31_2016.zip` file since it's only a documentation refresh but `p8docs521_refresh_10_07_2015.zip` file
3. unzip the `p8docs521_refresh_10_07_2015.zip` file and give `p8docs521_refresh_10_07_2015\com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc_5.2.1.jar` file as the Javadoc's archive path in Eclipse Javadoc Location menu.

Now you can have Javadocs for Content Engine Java API attached to jace.jar